# Pass custom error code (ERRCODE) with a plpy.error or a custom SPIError

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, plpython

Is it possible to pass a custom error code with `plpy.error/fatal` or inherit `SPIError` to pass a custom ERRCODE, HINT, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While poking through the plpython source, a way I found so far, is to inherit from SPIError and set `sqlstate`

```
raise type('MyError', (plpy.SPIError,), {'sqlstate': 'D000M'})(...)
```

will propagate the ERRCODE `D000M` and works for me.

A nice to have would be to define a custom HINT too but looks more tricky, since it comes with `spidata`.

Comment: It is strange to see this workaround, although a fix of this missing feature can be four hour work :(. PostgreSQL is open source, if somebody miss some feature, the he should to send a proposal for this feature. Python has all features for implementation user friendly plpy.error function with support DETAIL, HINT, SQLCODE.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution how to do it. Use a instance of `SPIError` class, and set a `spidata` property.

```
postgres=# do $$
x = plpy.SPIError('Nazdarek'); 
x.spidata = (0, "Some detail", "some hint", None, -1); 
raise x;
$$ language plpythonu;

ERROR:  plpy.SPIError: Nazdarek
DETAIL:  Some detail
HINT:  some hint
CONTEXT:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  PL/Python anonymous code block, line 4, in <module>
    raise x;
PL/Python anonymous code block
```

Errcode should be entered as integer value, what is pretty unfriendly. I'll look how to translate it better.